# Type error with map based on cache in Guava

Tags: java, generics, guava

I'm trying to use Guava to simulate a LRU map.

```
Map<K, V> map = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .maximumSize(maxSize)
        .build() // not using a cache loader
        .asMap();
```

But when I try do this I get an error.

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ConcurrentMap<Object,Object> to Map<K,V>
```

However, if I create the Map with a temporary reference to the cache it works fine.

```
Cache<K, V> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .maximumSize(maxSize)
        .build();
Map<K, V> map = cache.asMap();
```

Why does this work and the first sample doesn't?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's Java's generics fault - generic types cannot be inferred in this case. You should add `<K, V>` to tell Java to treat newly created cache as `Cache<K, V>`, not `Cache<Object, Object>`.

```
private static <K, V> Map<K, V> makeMap(final int maxSize) {
  return CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
      .maximumSize(maxSize)
      .<K, V>build() // not using a cache loader
      .asMap();
}
```

and then it'll work:

```
final Map<Long, String> map = makeMap(10);
```

See [this part of Angelika Langer's *Java Generics FAQs*](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ403).

Answer (score 1):

Here's my derivation from Xaerxess' answer, usage:

```
private final Map<String, List<Condition>> waitersByKey=MapUtil.create(5, 1000);
```

MapUtil.java:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder;
import com.google.common.cache.RemovalListener;

public class MapUtil {

  /**
   * Value for items which are unrestricted (-1)
   */
  public static final int UNRESTRICTED=-1;

  /**
   * Create a generic map that will not exceed max size
   * @param maxSize
   * @return created map
   */
  public static <K,V> Map<K,V> createWithMaxSize(int maxSize) {
    return create(UNRESTRICTED,maxSize);
  }

  /**
   * Create a generic map that will expire objects if not accessed within a given number of minutes
   * @param expireInMins
   * @return created map
   */
  public static <K,V> Map<K,V> createWithExpiration(int expireInMins) {
    return create(expireInMins,UNRESTRICTED,UNRESTRICTED);
  }

  /**
   * Creates a map with an initial size.  Reduces growth performance hit.
   * @param initialSize
   * @return created map
   */
  public static <K,V> Map<K,V> createWithInitialSize(int initialSize) {
    return create(UNRESTRICTED,UNRESTRICTED,initialSize);
  }

  /**
   * Create generic map that expires values with max size
   * @param expireInMins max age of unaccessed items in minutes, or UNRESTRICTED
   * @param maxSize max number of items before oldest is removed, or UNRESTRICTED
   * @return created map
   */
  public static <K,V> Map<K,V> create(int expireInMins, int maxSize) {
    return create(expireInMins,maxSize,UNRESTRICTED);
  }

  /**
   * Create generic map that expires values with max size
   * @param expireInMins max age of unaccessed items in minutes, or UNRESTRICTED
   * @param maxSize max number of items before oldest is removed, or UNRESTRICTED
   * @param removalListener listener called on item removal, if not null
   * @return created map
   */
  public static <K,V> Map<K,V> create(int expireInMins, int maxSize, RemovalListener<K, V> removalListener) {
    return create(expireInMins,maxSize,UNRESTRICTED, removalListener);
  }

  /**
   * Convenience method to build a Guava cache as generic map.
   * http://stackoverflow.com/a/14730359/303442
   * @param expireInMins max age of unaccessed items in minutes, or UNRESTRICTED
   * @param maxSize max number of items before oldest is removed, or UNRESTRICTED
   * @param initialCapacity initial size in elements, reduces growth performance hit. UNRESTRICTED for default
   * @return created map
   */
  public static <K,V> Map<K,V> create(int expireInMins, int maxSize, int initialCapacity) {
    return create(expireInMins,maxSize,initialCapacity,null);
  }

  /**
   * Convenience method to build a Guava cache as generic map.
   * http://stackoverflow.com/a/14730359/303442
   * @param expireInMins max age of unaccessed items in minutes, or UNRESTRICTED
   * @param maxSize max number of items before oldest is removed, or UNRESTRICTED
   * @param initialCapacity initial size in elements, reduces growth performance hit. UNRESTRICTED for default
   * @param removalListener listener called on item removal, if not null
   * @return created map
   */
  public static <K,V> Map<K,V> create(int expireInMins, int maxSize, int initialCapacity,RemovalListener<K, V> removalListener) {
    CacheBuilder<Object, Object> builder = CacheBuilder.newBuilder();
    if (expireInMins>-1)
      builder.expireAfterWrite(expireInMins, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    if (maxSize>-1)
      builder.maximumSize(1000);
    if (initialCapacity>-1)
      builder.initialCapacity(initialCapacity);
    if (removalListener!=null)
      builder.removalListener(removalListener);
    return builder.<K,V>build().asMap();
  }
}
```